# Как достучаться до значение в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Как можно заменить знаки вопроса? Достучаться до элементов если не знаешь имя

```js
var layerGroup = [];

var nameArray = (el.array);
layerGroup.push({
  [el.value]: {
    name: el.value,
    img: 'img/layers/' + el.value + '.png',
    price: priceTop,
    height: heightLayerTop
  }
});

// console.log(layerGroup[0].?????????.name);
// console.log(layerGroup[0].?????????.img);
// console.log(layerGroup[0].?????????.price);
// console.log(layerGroup[0].?????????.height);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Пишите код текстом.*

```
console.log(layerGroup[0][Object.keys(layerGroup[0])[0]].img);
```